# Getting constraints using loadNibNamed and Size Classes

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, xib, size-classes

I'm loading a view from a xib using Autolayout and Size Classes. Inside that view there's a subview, `viewWithSizeClasses`, with a constraint on its height that depends on the size class.

What I'm trying to do is to load constraints right after `loadNibNamed` in order to get the proper height according to the current Size Class.

I tried various combinations of `layoutSubviews()`, `updateConstraints()` but no matter what I do I'm always getting the default *Any, Any* height.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let xibView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View", owner: self, options: nil).first as View

    self.view.addSubview(xibView)
    height = xibView.viewWithSizeClasses.frame.size.height // <- Any, Any height
}
```

I'm deploying on iOS8 or newer.

Comment: Did you ever fixed that?

Comment: Nope, apparently this is not possible. :-/

Comment: So size classes are basically useless outside Storyboard? :/

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. Autolayout and Size Class work perfectly fine when used in .XIB files. What I was trying to figure out is if there was a way to force the autolayout engine to kick in right after getting the view from loadwithnib. If you wait for the normal chain to complete you will get the correct constraints you've set in IB. I'm pretty sure you'll have a similar issue using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same trouble trying to use the same xib with separate constraints for iPhone vs iPad. My solution was to create a view for each size class within the same xib. Then when loading the xib, access the proper view by index. In my case, my Any-Any size class is at index 0 and Regular-Regular at index 1.

```
NSArray *views = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view = views[IS_IPAD];
```

I'm sure you can translate that to Swift. I've also defined a global macro

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```